# NT Service\MSSQL$DEV

Tags: sql-server, service

I have these services running
I was supposed to change only the SQL Server Agent service but by mistake changed couple of SQL SERVER STORAGE PROCESSING SERVICES which was using

NT Service\MSSQL$DEV account. If I had to put it back how would I do it, as this is not a local service account correct? I do not see anything as NT Service locally on the server.

How can I put back the same NT Service account or chose the account so that the password gets filled automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MSSQL$DEV` is the service name (not the service display name) then that's a virtual account.

From the [Service Accounts Step-by-Step Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd548356(v=ws.10)):

> To configure a service to use a virtual account
>
> - Click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Services.
> - In the details pane, right-click the service that you want to configure, and then click Properties.
> - Click the Log On tab, click This account, and then type `NT SERVICE\ServiceName`. When you are finished, click OK.
> - Restart the service for the change to take effect.